# Short story about intelligent alien life mocking humans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There is a short story I read a while back, in which intelligent alien life form discuss whether to include human beings into some kind of advanced society if life forms. But humans are mocked for conducting nuclear tests on earth rather than in space. I can't remember the title or the author. Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  (When was "a while back?")

Comment: I read it about 2 years ago. I was asked to review a short story, but i can't recall the title. The entire content of this story is about 1 page. Tried googling it, but no help. Sorry, I dont know much more.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Possibly [Silly Asses](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46103) by Isaac Asimov. It's a very short story as you describe. It ends:

> But if they have thermonuclear power, where then do they conduct their tests and detonations?”
>
> “On their own planet, sir.”
>
> Naron rose to his full twenty feet of height and thundered, “On their own planet?”
>
> “Yes, sir.”
>
> Slowly Naron drew out his stylus and passed a line through the latest addition in the smaller book. It was an unprecedented act, but, then, Naron was very wise and could see the inevitable as well as anyone in the galaxy.
> “Silly asses,” he muttered.

The story is probably also the subject of the question [Short story about humans entering the galactic civilization](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97041/short-story-about-humans-entering-the-galactic-civilization) although the answer to that question was never accepted.

Comment: Just as a side note, I would disagree with OP’s interpretation of the ending.  Naron is not “mocking” humanity, but concluding regretfully that humanity is not going to survive much longer.  (“Naron […] could see the inevitable”.)

Answer (score 1):

For humor's sake, [*They're Made out of Meat*](https://www.mit.edu/people/dpolicar/writing/prose/text/thinkingMeat.html) might deserve mention.  That story doesn't touch upon nuclear testing, but it is pretty darn funny, and it definitely has more of a mocking tone.    Full text available at the link.